# Is hardware abstraction enough for HUGE amount of files?

Tags: web-server, network-storage

The web application I'm working on, will be used to upload/download large number/amounts of smaller size files - I'm looking at close to 1B files with total size of > 10Pb. I'm currently struggling with deciding the scalable architecture that would support such amounts. 
And here's my question - is there a way of building some sort of storage that would be seen by a windows server as one huge (10Pb and up) network storage drive, so I can write all the files to subfolders of that virtual drive? And how would it perform?

Right now I'm trying to understand if that's even possible, or if I have to implement software level sharding - writing files to different drives based on some key.

I'm a developer, not a sys admin, so I apologize if it's a naive question, and thanks in advance for patience in explaining me possibly trivial things.

Andrey

Comment: I would research if SQL Server filestreams + NTFS can handle this.

Comment: You mean, store files "in" SQL Server?

Comment: the FileStream data type is a special kind of field. It does not store the data in the database (this would be **bad**) but it's kinda like holding the file on the disk and the metadata in the SQL server, but integrated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as a 'normal but huge' fileserver:

- [glusterfs](http://www.gluster.org)
- [lustrefs](http://wiki.lustre.org/index.php/Main_Page)

with a file-like application level library:

- amazon S3
- rackspace cloudfiles
- [mogilefs](http://www.danga.com/mogilefs/)

generic key-value:

- mongoDB
- BDB
- [tokyo cabinet](http://fallabs.com/tokyocabinet/)
- ... lots others

Answer (score 1):

[Check out how Backblaze is storing its data.](http://blog.backblaze.com/2009/09/01/petabytes-on-a-budget-how-to-build-cheap-cloud-storage/) Very good read and they have a blog about the new 3TB drives.  This probably will not answer the question about file system.  I am not sure how Backblaze does there file structure.  But good information nevertheless.

Comment: They have a nice design, but the key concern is performance - a single server with just one processor and 4Gb of memory can't be speedy serving 45 drives.
But it's an interesting read, so +1

Comment: Ah - it can. Sorry. One processor is 6 cores these days. 4gb memory for a simple FS + Linux is enough. discs is 25% of the capacity of a RAID card like from Adaptec's 5xxx series. You should be more concerned with bandwidth (go go infiniband, 10gb here) which is going to be the botttlenech.

Answer (score 1):

Before you continue looking, you need to decide a bit more exactly what kind of semantics you need.  For instance, you say they're files - do you need POSIX file semantics (mostly concerned with consistency and locking) on them on the storage?  or is 'eventual consistency' of various distributed datastores enough?  What are your I/O requirements: how much concurrent access?  What are your redundancy requirements?  Also: what kind of hardware are you going to use?  10Pb arrays don't grow on trees and just managing them is a full time job - that much hardware means failure is a normal event, so constant repair and replacement is needed.

From what you've said "web application... storing files..." I think an [OpenStack](http://openstack.org/) or [S3](http://s3.amazonaws.com/) kind of solution should do you.  Since you're mostly a developer, I'd suggest you probably want to actually use amazon or [Rackspace](http://www.rackspacecloud.com/cloud_hosting_products/files) or whoever as your provider unless you really want to get into the hardware management biz.

Answer (score 0):

These days you might consider HDFS and the general Hadoop ecosystem.